# Allow negative integer value input for Datagridview C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to input negative integer value (minus sign (-)) for Datagridview but whenever I type - sign into the Datagridview. An exeption dialog display: *Input string was not a correct format.*  The Datasource of this cell is Integer column in SQL server.
How can we handle this exception? Please help. 
I googled and found that almost people need to prevent negative value input but in my case need to allow negative value input.

Comment: You need to share the relevant code for us to understand what could be wrong with it and how to correct it.

Comment: Unless you are not sharing the grid column configuration code, it is hard to tell.
Just for a heads up, Please check the column properties and check if any formatting is applied in that field.